# Send LatLong to Server

Tags: android, ip-address

I've created a Lat-Long application that needs to send the received Lat-Long to a server and store it in my database. Please suggest me how to send lat-long to server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, you can use a php script which receive lat and long as parameters and parse them to the query..

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", lng));

try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://yourserver.com/script.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();               
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", e.toString());
            return false;
            //Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```